# How do I use LZ-String when uploading HTML to server?

Tags: javascript, ajax

The following HTML/JS test page uploads LZ-compressed content (an HTML table) to a PHP test script that returns the uploaded content to the browser.

With the HTML as shown, the returned content does *not* match the sent content. However, if you make some minor changes to the HTML (e.g., change the word "HELLO" to "HEADING", or remove the thead), it works.

In both cases (i.e., the comparison yielding true or false result), the characters are seemingly the same and pass in a diff-checker.

I have not checked `LZString.compressToBase64()` since I was hoping for better compression.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>LZ-String Test</title>
        
        <style>
            table {border-collapse: collapse;}
            th, td {border: 1px solid black;}
        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lz-string/1.4.4/lz-string.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var content = `
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>HELLO</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>10</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            `;
        
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var formData = new FormData();
                var compressedContent = LZString.compress(content);
                formData.append("fileContent", compressedContent);
            
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "test.php",
                    data: formData,
                    cache: false,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false
                    
                }).done(function(data) {
                    var result = JSON.parse(data);
                    if (result.result == "success") {
                        $("body").append("<p>This is the html I compressed:<br>" + content + "</p>");
                        $("body").append("<p>This is what I sent to the server:<br>" + result.received + ".</p>");
                        $("body").append("<p>This is what I received from the server:<br>" + result.received + ".</p>");
                        $("body").append("<p>Using ===, what was sent matches what was returned is " + (compressedContent === result.received) + ".</p>");
                        $("body").append("<p>Using localCompare, what was sent matches what was returned is " + (compressedContent.localeCompare(result.received) === 0) + ".</p>");
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>

<?php
    $content = $_REQUEST["fileContent"];
    echo json_encode(array ("result" => "success", "received" => $content));
?>
```

Comment: The issue is when you put the compressed string into formdata - if you compare `formData.get("fileContent")` with `compressedContent` it doesn't match

Comment: try  `compressToEncodedURIComponent` (just as bad compression as `compressToBase64`) or, if your server can handle it - `compressToUTF16`

Comment: @Jaromanda X:  Thank you. All of your suggestions worked. And trying what you suggested in your first comment never occurred to me. Do you want to post your comment as an answer, so that I can officially accept it?